# Clojure JDBC: MySQL errors when creating table with composite unique constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, clojure

I have tried creating the following table with the below unique constraint. I receive the same MySQL error for the below code, as well as three similar variations that my research suggested should work.

```
(defn create-prices-table [db]
  (db-do-commands db (create-table-ddl :prices
                                            [:priceid :integer "PRIMARY KEY" "AUTO_INCREMENT"]
                                            [:productid :integer "references products (productid)"]
                                            [:date "date"]
                                            [:price "decimal(7,2)"]
                                            :table-spec "UNIQUE KEY `uc_price` (`productid`, `date`)")))
```

Other tries...

```
;; :table-spec "UNIQUE `uc_price` (`productid`, `date`)"
;; :table-spec "constraint uc_price unique (productid, date)"
;; :table-spec "constraint `uc_price` unique (`productid`, `date`)"
```

The message that I receive when attempting to execute...

```
CompilerException java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIQUE KEY `uc_price` (`productid`, `date`)' at line 1, compiling:(schema_test.clj:38:41)
```

I am using version 0.3.5 of the clojure.java.jdbc library.

**Edit**

create-string-ddl returns

```
"CREATE TABLE prices (priceid integer PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, productid integer references products (productid), date date, price decimal(7,2)) UNIQUE KEY `uc_price` (`productid`, `date`)"
```

Comment: what string do you get from the `create-table-ddl` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at the [Clojure code](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/blob/0fea524f92425c6009d403fb2ed3dedb0565ab78/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/jdbc.clj#L1041) behind this, and it doesn't seem to support constraint clauses. You might be able to abuse the API by doing something like:

```
(create-table-ddl :prices
    [:priceid :integer "PRIMARY KEY" "AUTO_INCREMENT"]
    [:productid :integer "references products (productid)"]
    [:date "date"]
    [:price "decimal(7,2), CONSTRAINT UNIQUE KEY `uc_price` (`productid`, `date`)"])
```

That said, you're already at the point where you're embedding MySQL specific syntax. You might as well just write the create table statement yourself.

Unfortunately `:table-spec` is for things that appear outside the parentheses in `create table`. See [table_option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) in the MySQL documents.